# How to get answer from first try of quiz and second try of same quiz as first try in database

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have created a quiz with the answer options a, b, c and I want to get an answer from that option and save it to the database. How to save in the database so that the answer from the first try of the quiz is different from the second trial answer from the quiz, so that I can get the answer and call in the answer to be calculate in score function of the quiz?

what i have tried :

in my controller

```
         public function score($id){
            $user_login = Auth::user()->id;
            $answers = Answer::select('user_answer')->where('jenis_quiz_id','=',$id)->where('user_id','=',$user_login)->get();//get the answer

            unset($a);
            unset($b);
            unset($c);
            $a = 0;
            $b = 0;
            $c = 0;
            if($answers->count()) {
                foreach ($answers as $answer) {
                    switch ($answer->user_answer) {
                        case 1:
                        $a++;
                        break;
                        case 2:
                        $b++;
                        break;
                        case 3:
                        $c++;   
                        break;
                    }

                        }

                        return $a+$b+$c;



                    }
                    public function getShowResultOfQuiz($id){
                        $categoryquiz= JenisQuiz::findOrFail($id);
                        $user= Auth::user()->id;
                        // $instansi = Auth::user()->instansi;
                        // $kelas = Auth::user()->kelas;

                        $score= $this->score($id);

                        $kelas = Auth::user()->kelas;
                        $instansi = Auth::user()->instansi;

                        History::create([
                            'user_id'=>$user,
                            'jenis_quiz_id'=>$id,
                            'score'=> $score,
                            'kelas' => $kelas,
                            'instansi' => $instansi
                            ]);

                            // $time_taken = date("H:i:s", strtotime(Answer::whereJenisQuizId($id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->time_taken));
                            switch ($id) {
                                case '1':
                                return view('user.pages.quizresult',compact('score','categoryquiz'));
                                break;

                                case '2':
                                return view('user.pages.quizanxietyresult',compact('score','categoryquiz'));
                                break;

                                case '3':
                                return view('user.pages.quizdepresiresult',compact('score','categoryquiz'));
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                    }
```

problem : can't distinguish answers from the first try of quiz trial and second try of quiz
(from same quiz form but i taken it twice, and how to make the difference between it.

My code result above is score from first try added to the second try,how to not added it??????

Comment: Why don't you make a answers table with answers and different trials? And store answer in that one if it's submitted second time by same user.

Comment: thanks for answering, actually I want to make a trial column in the answer model, but how do I send it to the function score()? like  $answers = Answer::select('user_answer')->where('jenis_quiz_id','=',$id)->where('trial','=','??')where('user_id','=',$user_login)->get();

Comment: `$answers = Answer::where('user_id', $user->id)->pluck('trial_1');` assuming you have a trial_1 column in your answers table, pluck will give you all the values of this column

Comment: so , every i attempt quiz, and submit it, it will add new column trial_$id in database, and data will saved there?